# Access controller in another controller class

Tags: controller, javafx-2

I have root layout containing 2 layouts:
- OptionsPane
- DrawArea

What i am trying is to access DrawAreaController in OptionsPaneController to call its draw method. Below is initialize method from OptionsPaneController:

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        newDragonButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(newDragonButton.getText().equals("Nowy")){
                    //do something
                }

                else{
                    newDragonButton.setText("Nowy");

                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/DrawArea.fxml"));
                    DrawAreaController dac = (DrawAreaController) loader.getController();
                    Dragon dragon = new Dragon(600, 300, 20, 2, 90, 270, colorChooser.getValue());
                    if(dac == null)
                        System.out.println("controller = null");
                    dac.drawDragon(dragon);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately dac is always null.

Is there any mistake in my code or is it impossible to load controller in another controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller is always null, because you never load the FXMLLoader.

The [`load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) loads the fxml and instantiates the controller instance for you. If you do not use this method before `getController()`, it will always return `null`

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/DrawArea.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
DrawAreaController dac = (DrawAreaController) loader.getController();
```

*You may or may not want to store the root of the FXML..*

Comment: Thank you @ItachiUchiha for your answer.