# FXMLLoader use; adding data to a component controlled by another controller

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to add data to a `TableView` that has a different controller than the main application. After some tinkering, I did this for some time with a static `TableView` and a static method for calling the updates. However, I've run into problems with this approach elsewhere in the code and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237356/access-controller-in-another-controller-class) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995359/how-do-i-access-a-ui-element-from-another-controller-class-in-javafx/21996083) [research](https://riptutorial.com/javafx/example/8803/passing-data-to-fxml---accessing-existing-controller) led me to believe that the `FXMLLoader` might help.

But the data that should be added does not show up in the table. The `System.out.println("adding info");` shows up in the console twice as expected, but the table stays empty. It was populated when using the static approach. I am guessing my `FXMLLoader` is creating a different instance than the one that was created at program start. What is the problem in the code below, mostly in the main class the showMainStage part?

Main class:

```
package test.controller;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InteractionTest extends Application {

    private Stage mainStage;

    /**
     * Show the main window.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void showMainStage() throws IOException {
        final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        final Parent root = loader.load();
        final BorderPane bp = (BorderPane) root;
        mainStage = new Stage();
        mainStage.setScene(new Scene(bp));
        mainStage.setTitle("Interaction test");
        mainStage.setMaximized(false);
        mainStage.show();

        final Info i1 = new Info("1");
        i1.setPosition(1);
        i1.setTitle("Info 1");
        final Info i2 = new Info("2");
        i2.setPosition(2);
        i2.setTitle("Info 2");
        final List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
        infoList.add(i1);
        infoList.add(i2);
        final FXMLLoader tableLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/InfoTable.fxml"));
        final Parent parent = tableLoader.load();
        final InfoTableController itc = (InfoTableController) tableLoader.getController();
        itc.updateTable(infoList);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage initStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            showMainStage();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

TableController:

```
package test.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.SortType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

/**
 * Holds a {@link TableView} to display the infos for further interaction. Is
 * the controller for InfoTable.fxml.
 *
 */
public class InfoTableController {

    /**
     * A {@link ScrollPane} for the {@link Info} table.
     */
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane infoTablePane;

    /**
     * A {@link TableView} for the {@link Info}s.
     */
    private final TableView<Info> table = new TableView<>();

    /**
     * Build the column headers during initialization.
     */
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        final TableColumn<Info, String> positionColumn = new TableColumn<>("#");
        positionColumn.setEditable(false);
        positionColumn.setPrefWidth(15.0);
        positionColumn.setMaxWidth(50.0);
        positionColumn.setSortable(true);
        positionColumn.setSortType(SortType.ASCENDING);
        positionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("position"));
        final TableColumn<Info, String> titleColumn = new TableColumn<>("Title");
        titleColumn.setEditable(true);
        titleColumn.setPrefWidth(200.0);
        titleColumn.setMaxWidth(1000.0);
        titleColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("title"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(positionColumn, titleColumn);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.getSortOrder().add(positionColumn);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            final String id = newValue.getId();
            final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/InfoDisplay.fxml"));
            try {
                final Parent parent = loader.load();
            } catch (final IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            final InfoDisplayController idc = (InfoDisplayController) loader.getController();
            idc.displayDocument(id);
        });
        infoTablePane.setContent(table);
        infoTablePane.setFitToWidth(true);
        infoTablePane.setFitToHeight(true);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the {@link #table}.
     */
    public void sortTable() {
        table.sort();
    }

    /**
     * Adds table entries.
     *
     */
    public void updateTable(final List<Info> infoList) {
        table.getItems().clear();
        for (final Info info : infoList) {
            System.out.println("adding info");
            table.getItems().add(info);
        }
    }
}
```

DisplayController:

```
package test.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

/**
 * Displays infos for reading. Controller for InfoDisplay.fxml.
 *
 */
public class InfoDisplayController {

    @FXML
    private TabPane infoDisplayTabPane;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public InfoDisplayController() {

    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        infoDisplayTabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("test in class"));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the selected document in tabs.
     *
     * @param id The selected document's id.
     */
    public void displayDocument(final String id) {
        // get the underlying Lucene document with the id; omitted for this example
        System.out.println("attempting to display " + id);
        infoDisplayTabPane.getTabs().clear();
        final TextArea textArea = new TextArea("My info text.");
        final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(textArea);
        final Tab tab = new Tab("info", scrollPane);
        infoDisplayTabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
    }
}
```

Info object:

```
package test.controller;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Info {

    /**
     * The id as pulled from the Lucene index.
     */
    private final String id;

    /**
     * The position.
     */
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty position = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    /**
     * The title.
     */
    private final SimpleStringProperty title = new SimpleStringProperty("Title");

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public Info(final String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getPosition() {
        return position.get();
    }

    public void setPosition(final int position) {
        this.position.set(position);
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title.get();
    }

    public void setTitle(final String title) {
        this.title.set(title);
    }
}
```

Main.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane"
    fx:controller="test.controller.InteractionTest"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <top>
    </top>
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="HORIZONTAL"
            focusTraversable="true">
            <items>
                <fx:include source="InfoTable.fxml" />
                <fx:include source="InfoDisplay.fxml" />
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
    <bottom>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

InfoTable.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<ScrollPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="test.controller.InfoTableController"
    fx:id="infoTablePane">
</ScrollPane>
```

InfoDisplay.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    prefHeight="500" prefWidth="500" minHeight="200" minWidth="200"
    fx:controller="test.controller.InfoDisplayController">
    <center>
        <TabPane fx:id="infoDisplayTabPane"><Tab text="test"></Tab></TabPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load a fxml using `FXMLLoader` and modify the resulting scene via controller, this has no effect on any scenes created based on the same fxml with another `FXMLLoader.load` call.

Your code assumes this is the case though:

After calling `loader.load();` there are:

- 2 instances of `InteractionTest`; only one of those is used as controller
- 1 version of the `InfoTable.fxml` that is created based on `<fx:include source="InfoTable.fxml" />` and one instance of `InfoTableController` that is used for the part of the scene.

Later in the `showMainStage` method you create another version of this scene together with another `InfoTableController` instance using `tableLoader.load()`. You never show this scene, but this is the only one you initialize the table for. For the first version of the fxml you never do this initialisation.

There is a similar issue in your listener to the selected item in the table.

I don't recommend using the `Application` class as controller. Instead create a seperate controller class and use it to pass the data to/between the nested fxmls:

#### Main.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane"
    fx:controller="test.controller.MainController"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <center>
        <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="HORIZONTAL"
            focusTraversable="true">
            <items>
                <fx:include fx:id="table" source="InfoTable.fxml" />
                <fx:include fx:id="display" source="InfoDisplay.fxml" />
            </items>
        </SplitPane>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

```
public class MainController {

    // fields for injection of nested controllers
    @FXML
    private InfoDisplayController displayController;
    @FXML
    private InfoTableController tableController;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // connect selected table item with displayed document
        tableController.selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            final String id = newValue.getId();
            displayController.displayDocument(id);
        });
    }

    public void updateTable(final List<Info> infoList) {
        tableController.updateTable(infoList);
    }
}
```

```
public class InfoTableController {

    ...

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        ...
//        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
//            final String id = newValue.getId();
//            final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/InfoDisplay.fxml"));
//            try {
//                final Parent parent = loader.load();
//            } catch (final IOException e1) {
//                e1.printStackTrace();
//            }
//            final InfoDisplayController idc = (InfoDisplayController) loader.getController();
//            idc.displayDocument(id);
//        });
        ...
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Info> selectedItemProperty() {
        return table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty();
    }
}
```

```
private void showMainStage() throws IOException {
    final Info i1 = new Info("1");
    i1.setPosition(1);
    i1.setTitle("Info 1");
    final Info i2 = new Info("2");
    i2.setPosition(2);
    i2.setTitle("Info 2");
    final List<Info> infoList = new ArrayList<>();
    infoList.add(i1);
    infoList.add(i2);

    final FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
    final Parent root = loader.load();
    ((MainController)loader.getController()).updateTable(infoList);
    ...


//    final FXMLLoader tableLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/InfoTable.fxml"));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has cleared it up for me. Initially, I kept wondering how the two @FXML fields in MainController were assigned. But it turns out I was missing the fx:id="table" and fx:id="display" attributes in the Main.fxml. Somehow, the "Controller" bit in the variable name, e.g. tableController, seems to be supplied automatically. Is that correct, or am I still missing something?

Comment: @ramundsen You always append `Controller` to the `fx:id` to get the field name, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467982/javafx8-fxml-naming-of-nested-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Well your DataTable have no relation to the MainStage you initialized earlier. The included Datatable in the FXML-File is a different from your created one afterwards. I would suggest that you create a Node in your Main.fxml and when you load the second file, you override this node. For example, one of my code bases contains:

```
loadingWidget.start();
    Task <Parent> task = new Task<Parent>() {
        @Override
        protected Parent call() throws Exception {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/translationCreator.fxml"));

            return loader.load();
        }       
    };

    task.setOnFailed(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            loadingWidget.close();
            task.getException().printStackTrace();
            Notifications.create().title("Something went wrong!").text("Error while loading resource tableWindow.fxml").show(); 
        }       
    });

    task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler <WorkerStateEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
            loadingWidget.close();
            contentPane.getChildren().clear();
            contentPane.getChildren().add(task.getValue()); 
        }           
    });

    new Thread(task).start();
```

So i just added my new Node to the Content Pane, i defined in my FXML-File. Afterwards this should easily work, you don't have to define something like Static Controllers. If you can't understand this, i will try to give you a full example :)